# 301 redirect for old URL's with regular expression through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to implement 301 redirect from old web-site to new web-site url structure (custom CMS). In my example I am trying to redirect this structure:

```
/shop/my-product-name
```

to

```
/fr/my-product-name
```

This is what I have, but the web-site shows me empty page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/shop/(.*)$ /fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de|es|it)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de|es|it)/news/?$ index.php?lang=$1&section=blogposts [QSA,L]
```

it seems to me that the code is absolutely fine. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)?$ fr/$2 [R=301,L]
```

as it happens the problem was with leading slash in the beginning

Comment: _“set up the "shop" part into parentheses to turn it into a variable”_ - that is not _really_ why it started working though. The actual error was that you tried to match a leading slash. When rewriting is configured in .htaccess context, the URL path the rules match against, never starts with a slash - that has been removed at this point already. Looks like you fixed this kinda “accidentally” here, while you introduced the grouping. But `RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /fr/$1 [R=301,L]` does the job.